# 70s novel about telepathic alien races fighting together

Tags: story-identification

A novel I read a long time ago.  Several races with different telepathic level ratings.  A group joined together to fight a mutant.  Location another planet.  Some races not telepathic but could shield their minds by concentrated thoughts.

Comment: Your description seems a bit vague. Can you add any other details?

Answer (score 3):

Don't have a high enough reputation to comment. From your description the two books that came to mind are The Rowan by Anne McCaffrey or the Lensman Series by E. E. Smith. Neither book matches everything on your list, but they are close. The only thing either series does not match is "shield their minds by concentrated thoughts".

[The Rowan](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/61938.The_Rowan?from_search=true&search_version=service) is a coming of age story about a telepathic girl who works for a corporation moving materials and goods around the galaxy. There is a ratings system, several planets, and a group does join together to fight the antagonist.

The Lensmen series is about a galactic police force (similar to the Jedi order) that slowly uncovers an enemy as the series goes on. There are lots planets, three rating levels for lensmen, and a group joins together several times to fight the various antagonists.

Comment: If you fleshed out why you think these are matches, you could turn this into a reasonable answer...

Comment: Richard is right: edit in a brief description of each of these books and this would be a good answer. See also [how to write a good story-ID answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9445/31394).

Comment: The Lensmen are like the Jedi!!! Sacrilege! :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie Lol. I'm often surprised that many of the similarities between Star Wars and the Lensmen are not remarked on more. It could be that I'm just not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

The novel this sounds like one named "Star Rangers" by Andre Norton, but was published earlier than what you said (published in 1953).  One of the subplots in this novel involves several Space Patrolmen, some of which who have telepathic powers, rated on a scale from 0 - 8 or more.  Those with a 0 have no abilities, those with a low rating can be trained to have a mental shield, and those with high ratings (5 and up as I recall) can actively sense, defend against, and mount mental attacks.  The antagonist in this novel was an alien mutant named Cumni who had very strong telepathic powers.